# How to parse a XML response in ansible?

Tags: xml-parsing, ansible

I'm running the panos_op ansible module and struggling to parse the output.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
  "result": {
    "changed": true, 
    "failed": false, 
    "msg": "Done", 
    "stdout": "{\"response\": {\"@status\": \"success\", \"result\": \"no\"}}", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "{\"response\": {\"@status\": \"success\", \"result\": \"no\"}}"
    ], 
    "stdout_xml": "<response status=\"success\"><result>no</result></response>"
  }
}
```

This is as close as I can get to assigning the value for "result".

```
ok: [localhost] => {
  "result.stdout": {
    "response": {
        "@status": "success", 
        "result": "no"
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is to set a conditional loop for the ansible task.

```
tasks:
- name: Checking for pending changes
panos_op:
  ip_address: '{{ host }}'
  password: '{{ operator_pw }}'
  username: '{{ operator_user}}'
  cmd: 'check pending-changes'
register: result
until: result.stdout.result = no
retries: 10
delay: 5
tags: check
```

How can I make this work?

**UPDATE:** I've tried it another way, but now I have a new issue trying to deal with a literal "<" char.

```
tasks:
- name: Checking for pending changes
panos_op:
  ip_address: '{{ host }}'
  password: '{{ operator_pw }}'
  username: '{{ operator_user}}'
  cmd: 'check pending-changes'
register: result

- fail:
   msg: The Firewall has pending changes to commit.
 when: '"<result>no"' not in result.stdout_xml
```

ERROR:
    did not find expected key

Any help at all would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I just mentioned [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336678/parse-ip-address-from-xml-ansible), since Ansible 2.4, there's [an xml module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/xml_module.html#xml-module).

### Playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Get result from xml.
      xml:
        xmlstring: "<response status=\"success\"><result>no</result></response>"
        content: "text"
        xpath: "/response/result"
```

### Output

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Get result from xml.] ****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => changed=false
  actions:
    namespaces: {}
    state: present
    xpath: /response/result
  count: 1
  matches:
  - result: 'no'
  msg: 1
  xmlstring: |-
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <response status="success"><result>no</result></response>

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```