# Combining the output of multiple loops in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I am working with Ansible and in my playbook I am running the following task, in which I have multiple loops so as to retrieve different tags from a specific xml:

```
- name: Retrieve multiple xml tags valuei
  xml:
    xmlstring: "{{ item.string }}"
    xpath: "{{ item.path }}"
    content: text
  loop:
    - { path: "/rpc-reply/vlan-instance-information/vlan-instance-group/vlan-member/vlan-tag", string: "{{topology.xml}}" }
    - { path: "/rpc-reply/vlan-instance-information/vlan-instance-group/vlan-member/vlan-member-interface", string: "{{topology.xml}}" }
  register: tags_value

- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.matches }}"
  loop: "{{ tags_value.results }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.matches }}"
```

So I am getting the following:

```
ok: [sss-sd1-02] => (item=[{u'vlan-member-interface': u'et-0/0/0.0*'}, {u'vlan-member-interface': u'et-0/0/1.0*'}]) => {
"msg": [
    {
        "vlan-member-interface": "et-0/0/0.0*"
    }, 
    {
        "vlan-member-interface": "et-0/0/1.0*"
    }
]
```

}

and this

```
ok: [sss-sd1-02] => (item=[{u'vlan-tag': u'4071'}, {u'vlan-tag': u'4072'}]) => {
"msg": [
    {
        "vlan-tag": "4071"
    }, 
    {
        "vlan-tag": "4072"
    }
]
```

}

Is there a way to group "vlan-member-interface": "et-0/0/0.0*" and "vlan-tag": "4071" in 1 result , either in this task or in a different one ? And also is there a way to create a list with only {4071, 4072} ? Because i cannot handle it as it is right now !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be simplified. Let's have the data

```
    results:
      - [A: a1, A: a2]
      - [B: b1, B: b2]
```

---

> Q1: "*Group "A:a1" and "B:b1" in 1 result"*

A: Use `zip` function. For example

```
    - set_fact:
        my_groups: "{{ results.0|zip(results.1)|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_groups
```

gives

```
    "my_groups": [
        [
            {
                "A": "a1"
            }, 
            {
                "B": "b1"
            }
        ], 
        [
            {
                "A": "a2"
            }, 
            {
                "B": "b2"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

---

> Q2: *"Create a list with only [b1, b2]"*

A: Use `dict2items` and `json_query` functions. For example

```
   - set_fact:
        my_values: "{{ results.1|map('dict2items')|list|json_query('[].value') }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_values
```

gives

```
    "my_values": [
        "b1", 
        "b2"
    ]
```

---

<sup>Question 1 is substitution of: Group "vlan-member-interface": "et-0/0/0.0*" and "vlan-tag": "4071" in 1 result

Question 2 is substitution of: Create a list with only {4071, 4072}

Variable *results* is substitution of *tags_value.results*</sup>

Comment: my playbook has a task with 2 loops and i register the result in the variable tags_value. So what is the results.0 that you refer to for me ? If you see my results i have this item-msg. @VladimirBotka

Comment: I am not sure how to handle the return value (this item-msg).. I am trying to handle the tags_value as a list but it is not ..In particular, instead of results.0 i do: tags_value.vlan-member-interface but is not working !!!

Comment: To answer your question "What is the results.0 ?".  This is the first element of the list "results". In my answer the list "results" is substitution of registered results "tags_value.results".

Comment: Thank you @VladimirBotka , my xml was a little bit more complicated so i had to debug the return value first and see how to access those values , but thank you for show me how to handle the problem !!!

Comment: You're welcome !!! [minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) makes life easier.